# Free audio players for website streaming

Tags: javascript, html, flash, audio-streaming

Are there any free audio players that I can use in my website? Are they customizable?

I've heard of Soundmanager 2. It's a flash based player with a javascript front-end.

Are there any other free players like that?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545507/needs-a-good-mp3-audio-player-to-embed-in-my-website

Comment: Dupe II: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415889/embeddable-flash-based-mp3-player

Comment: Dupe for real streaming (most others just start playing before the download has finished): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363928/flash-streaming-player-shoutcast-mp3-aacplus-windows-media-audio

Comment: Dupe III: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590839/more-customizable-flash-mp3-player-for-website

Comment: Dupe IV: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065467/flash-mp3-player-with-javascript-controls

Comment: These are all great! Thanks so much. The only problem is that I want one (sorry I didn't say it earlier) that has support for the WAVE format. I couldn't find any on those that did....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like something that doesn't require loading a Flash plugin, try [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org).  It uses HTML 5 when the browser supports it.

Answer (score 1):

I like [this one](http://flash-mp3-player.net/). Simple to use and nice looking.